# Callable object in Kotlin or Swift

Tags: swift, oop, kotlin, functional-programming

Is it possible to create a `callable` object in `Kotlin` and/or `Swift`?

I have many objects that have just one method `execute`. The object is basically used as a closure. Some dependencies are captured during object construction. Some arguments are passed when the `execute` method is called.

The reason I’m not using plain functions is the classes implement interfaces and type checking is much more helpful though out the program.

Comment: Check this link https://touk.pl/blog/2015/10/11/kotlin-callable-and-executorservice/

Comment: Swift 5 will support this: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0216-dynamic-callable.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overload the [`invoke` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html):

```
class Callable(val prop: String) {
    operator fun invoke(para : String) {
        println("Invoke: $prop $para")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val c = Callable("prop")
    c("para")
}
```